# How do I get results using the submitJob function

Tags: dolphindb

I can submit a task asynchronously using the submitJob function, but how do I get the results ?

The code is as follows：

```
def Queryfun(){
    select * from table1 where date = 2019.04.29 and time >= 09:30:00
}
submitJob("Queryfun","Queryfun",  Queryfun)
```

Comment: This appears to be a Javascript question, not mysql. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html#submitjob

Answer (score 0):

The function getJobReturn(job_id, [blocking=false]) retrieves the batch job result.

If blocking is true,  the function will not return a value until the job is completed.